# With Twilio, can I use a POST method on a call create status_callback_method in python and get the parameter values

Tags: python, callback, twilio

I have successfully done this with a GET method:

```
    call = client.calls.create(
          method='POST',
          status_callback=twilioUrl+'/api/callstatus',
          status_callback_event=['initiated', 'ringing', 'answered', 'completed'],
          status_callback_method='GET',
          url=twilioUrl+'/api/createcallback',
          to=self.to_number,
          from_=self.from_number
          )
```

And here is the corresponding callback in FastAPI callback:

```
@app.get("/api/callstatus")
async def get(request: Request):
    query_params = request.query_params
    to_number = query_params.get('To', None)
    from_number = query_params.get('From', None)
    status = query_params.get('CallStatus', None)
    print("Call from: ",from_number," to: ", to_number," has status: ",status)
```

But if I try to switch to a POST method, I am unable to get the same parameters. Any suggestions on how I extract the same values from a similar POST method? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code can probably achieve the same while less lines as you explicitly state many defaults (e.g. `method='POST'`). This code should be a minimal example that shows how you can make a call and register a callback.

Keep in mind that the webhook needs to point to a [FQDN](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aiuv#:%7E:text=A%20fully%20qualified%20domain%20name,hostname%20and%20the%20domain%20name.), such as `https://mobert.ngrok.io/callback`:

```py
import os

import twilio.jwt.access_token
import twilio.jwt.access_token.grants
import twilio.rest
import logging
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask import Flask, request

# Load environment variables from a .env file
load_dotenv()

# Create a Twilio client
account_sid = os.environ["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"]
api_key = os.environ["TWILIO_API_KEY_SID"]
api_secret = os.environ["TWILIO_API_KEY_SECRET"]
caller = os.environ["TWILIO_NUMBER"]
callee = os.environ["MARIUS_NUMBER"]
twilio_client = twilio.rest.Client(api_key, api_secret, account_sid)

# Create a Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)


# Create a route that just returns "In progress"
@app.route("/")
def serve_homepage():
    return "In progress!"


@app.route('/callback', methods=['POST'])
def outbound():
    status = request.values.get('CallbackSource', None)
    from_number = request.values.get('From', None)
    logging.warning('Status: {}'.format(status))
    logging.warning('From: {}'.format(from_number))
    return ('', 204)


# Start the server when this file runs
if __name__ == "__main__":

    twilio_client.calls.create(
        url='http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml',
        to=callee,
        from_=caller,
        status_callback="https://mobert.ngrok.io/callback"
    )
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=3000, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, IObert. The issue I always had was that I couldn't get it to work in FastAPI. Flask didn't seem to be a problem.

I did finally figure out the issue. Was an issue in my code (of course). I needed to call request.form() versus request.query_params

```
@app.post("/api/callstatus")
async def callstatus(request: Request):
    form = await request.form()
    call_sid = form.get('CallSid', None)
    status = form.get('CallStatus', None)
    print("Call from: ",from_number," to: ", to_number," has status: ",status)
```

I spent a good amount of time getting to understand this so feel free to hit me up with more questions or code samples.